# Django Many-To-One Relationship add data to Many side

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have two models like below. I'm using Django restframework.

```
class Family(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Parishioner(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    family = models.ForeignKey(Family, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

There are my ViewSets

```
class FamilyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Family.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FamilySerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

class ParishionerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Parishioner.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ParishionerSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

These are my Serializers

```
class FamilySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Family
        fields = ('id', 'name')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)


class ParishionerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Parishioner
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'family')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
        depth = 1
```

So basically `Parishioner` can have one `Family`. `Family` has multiple `members(Parishioners)`

Currently I have to go to all `Parishioners` and select the `Family`.

is it possible to add a field called `members` to `Family` model, where members would be an `Array` of `Existing Parishioners` ?
or is there any other way to handle this ?

[image]

Comment: It would be a bad idea to do this at the database side, since that would mean the database does no longer check this. But you can easily do this in the serializer.

Answer (score 2):

It would be a bad idea to do this at the database side, since that would mean the database does no longer check this.

But you can easily do this in the serializer. We do this by adding an instance of the `ParishionerSerializer` to the `FamilySerializer`. We need to define the `ParishionerSerializer` *before* the `FamilySerializer`, since otherwise, that identifier is not yet assigned:

```
class ParishionerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Parishioner
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'family')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
        depth = 1


class FamilySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parishioner_set = ParishionerSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Family
        fields = ('id', 'name')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

You can rename it to `members` at the model layer and then update the serializer accordingly, or only in the subserializer.

## Option 1: use `related_name=…`

We can rename the relation in reverse to `memebers` by specifying a value for the [**`related_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name):

```
class Parishioner(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    family = models.ForeignKey(
        Family,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='members'
    )
```

then the serializer thus uses `member` instead:

```
class FamilySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    members = ParishionerSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Family
        fields = ('id', 'name')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

## Option 2: rename the serializer with `source=…`

We can also only specify this at the serializer level, by specifying a [**`source=…`** parameter [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source):

```
class FamilySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    members = ParishionerSerializer(
        source='parishioner_set',
        many=True,
        read_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Family
        fields = ('id', 'name')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It just list all "Parishioner" details in "Family 
" GET request. But I can't add "Parishioners" in "Family" Django api screen. Not in POST nor PUT. I added a screenshot in description

Comment: @AMendis: then you should remove the `read_only=True`.

Comment: I'm getting "Lists are not currently supported in HTML input." in Django screen

Comment: @AMendis: but that is only a matter of the *frontend*, not of the REST API itself.

Comment: ok got it now the problem is how to send the request.
I tried sending below request
{
    "name":"Mendis Family",
    "address":"No 30, Katukurunda",
    "members":[2]
}

but above request gives me below error
{
    "members": [
        {
            "non_field_errors": [
                "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."
            ]
        }
    ]
}
How to send the json data to members field ? id NOT enough ?

Comment: @AMendis: the idea is that you send a dictionary, so `{ "name": ..., "members": [{"first_name": ...., "last_name": ...}]}`.

Comment: purpose of this question is to add "Existing Parishioners" to "Family". Not add a new "Parishioner". Do I have to pass all information of existing "Parishioner" ?

Answer (score 0):

Fam = Family.objects.get(id=1)
Fam.parishioner_set.all()

This should do

Comment: where should I add it ?

Comment: Whenever you want to access the members of a particular family. Do this in your code.